# At what age are students addressed as вы instead of ты by their teachers?

Tags: этикет

I know that

- University professors are nearly always on вы with their students.
- School-age children are always addressed as ты by adults.

So at what stage in the education system does the switch from ты to вы happen?

Comment: Mileage varies greatly. I address my father-in-law as *ты* because we used to work together and at the same time address and am addressed by some of my friends back from the college as *вы* as a long running joke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my personal experience the switch happens when the student leaves school (around the age of 17) and goes to university. It depends on individual teachers of course. Some school teachers might address senior schoolchildren as `вы` in an attempt to promote their self-esteem and sense of responsibility. University students may get an occasional `ты`, especially if they are misbehaving. :)

Comment: I studied at phisics-mathematics school in the 8th-11th grades, all the teachers always addressed all the pupils as `вы`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a simple age separation.  It all depends on surroundings, teachers, students, school/institution, etc.

For example, in the school, from which I graduated, all teachers addressed all students as *вы* from 8th grade, that is, from about age 15 or so.

When I started university, all university students (in my uni) were normally addressed by teachers as *вы*. At the same time, some people that I studied with at the uni said that they were never called *вы* before starting the uni, that it, age 17 or so.

If you are ok to settle on a "soft" boundary, then I would say it's somewhere between 15 and 18 years old.

Outside the education, there's no clear separation whatsoever and the circumstances will dictate *вы* vs *ты*.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the transition happens when the student finishes the school. When he/she hands papers for entrance examinations to university, he/she is already called вы by the stuff.

Some high school students, especially in elite schools, are also called вы.  In some elite schools, all students are called вы.

It is not a matter of age. If university student is 16 years old, he/she will be called вы. [William James Sidis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_James_Sidis), if he lived today in Russia, would be called вы as a student of Russian university. If a school student is 18, he would still be called ты.